# Any option or suggestions to create the unique identifier in FlutterFlow?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-layout

Is there any option to create the unique identifier in FlutterFlow because. I want to create a record in different tables at the same time of the database. I need a unique identifier when i want to retrieve the data.
Example: like "price" table have should have a "productId"
I need to add an id of product document form product table in to the price  document of the price table

Answer (score 0):

There is a UUID pub package:

http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/uuid

you can use this package to get a unique id